# Passing multiple arguments in django view

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I have tree different users and I want to use one view function and three different forms. So I need to pass two arguments to `user_signup` view: the request object and the form Class. In urls.py I have the following code

```
path('signup/admin/', views.user_signup(request, AdminSignupForm), name='admin_signup')
```

in views.py I defined `user_signup` function

```
def user_signup(request, form, template_name='users/signup_staff.html'):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()  # save function is redefined in AdminSignupForm
    else:
        form = form()
    return render(request, template_name, {'form': form})
```

How can I pass a request object to `user_signup`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [the third argument](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/#passing-extra-options-to-view-functions) to the `path` function.

```
path('signup/admin/', views.user_signup, {'form': AdminSignupForm}, name='admin_signup')
```